# Closed form of the n-th term of the recurrence relation $x_{n+1}=x_{n}x_{n-1}+x_{n}+x_{n-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers, recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers

Let $x_{n} \in \mathbb Q$ be the n-th term of the recurrence relation
$$x_{n+1}=x_{n}x_{n-1}+x_{n}+x_{n-1}\;\;\;\;\;(1)$$
Given a subset $S \subset \mathbb N$, a solution of the relation $(1)$ is
$$x_{n}=\Big( \prod_{k\,\in\,S} p_{k}^{\,\alpha_k F_{n+\beta_k}} \Big)-1\;\;\;\;\;\alpha_k,\,\beta_k \in \mathbb Z\;\;\;\;\;(2)$$
where $p_k$ is the k-th prime number and $F_{n+\beta_k}$ indicates the term of index $n+\beta_k$ of the Fibonacci sequence.

$(2)$ is easily proved by direct substitution in $(1)$, remembering that $F_{i+1}=F_{i}+F_{i-1}$:
$$x_{n}x_{n-1}+x_{n}+x_{n-1} =$$
$$\Big( \prod_{k\,\in\,S} p_{k}^{\,\alpha_k F_{n+\beta_k}} -1 \Big) \Big( \prod_{k\,\in\,S} p_{k}^{\,\alpha_k F_{n-1+\beta_k}} -1 \Big) + \prod_{k\,\in\,S} p_{k}^{\,\alpha_k F_{n+\beta_k}} -1 + \prod_{k\,\in\,S} p_{k}^{\,\alpha_k F_{n-1+\beta_k}} -1 =$$
$$\prod_{k\,\in\,S} p_{k}^{\,\alpha_k(F_{n+\beta_k}+F_{n-1+\beta_k})} - \prod_{k\,\in\,S} p_{k}^{\,\alpha_k F_{n+\beta_k}} - \prod_{k\,\in\,S} p_{k}^{\,\alpha_k F_{n-1+\beta_k}} + 1 + \prod_{k\,\in\,S} p_{k}^{\,\alpha_k F_{n+\beta_k}} -1 + \prod_{k\,\in\,S} p_{k}^{\,\alpha_k F_{n-1+\beta_k}} - 1 =$$
$$\prod_{k\,\in\,S} p_{k}^{\,\alpha_k F_{n+1+\beta_k}} - 1 = x_{n+1}$$
Example 1 $(S=\{1\},\,\alpha_1=1,\,\beta_1=0)$ - [OEIS A063896](https://oeis.org/A063896):
$$x_0=0,\;x_1=1,\;x_n=2^{F_n}-1$$
Example 2 $(S=\{1,3\},\,\alpha_1=1,\,\alpha_3=1,\,\beta_1=-1,\,\beta_3=0)$:
$$x_0=1,\;x_1=4,\;x_n=2^{F_{n-1}}5^{F_{n}}-1$$
Example 3 $(S=\{1,2\},\,\alpha_1=2,\,\alpha_2=1,\,\beta_1=0,\,\beta_2=-1)$:
$$x_0=2,\;x_1=3,\;x_n=2^{2F_{n}}3^{F_{n-1}}-1$$
My question:

is it possible to generalize $(2)$ in order to put in a closed form all the sequences expressed by $(1)$?

Comment: Note that $$1+x_{n+1}=(1+x_n)(1+x_{n-1}),$$ and take $y_n=1+x_n$ (and logarithm). Then the solution is pretty straightforward.